# Selenium safari driver not working in python

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari

Safari browser gets closed immediately after launching the browser with

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

**Here is my env details**
Selenium 2.46.
Mac OS X 10.10.3 x86_64
Safari 8.0.5

**Here is my sample python code**

```
from selenium import webdriver

def test():
    driver = webdriver.Safari()
    driver.get("www.google.com")
```

**when I run the above function, I am getting the following output**

```
15:57:46.465 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
15:57:46.491 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 24.45-b08
15:57:46.491 INFO - OS: Mac OS X 10.10.3 x86_64
15:57:46.500 INFO - v2.46.0, with Core v2.46.0. Built from revision 87c69e2
15:57:46.551 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match the current platform MAC
15:57:46.552 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
15:57:46.552 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
15:57:46.603 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:50220/wd/hub
15:57:46.603 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
15:57:56.500 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{platform=ANY, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=safari, version=}]])
15:57:56.508 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{platform=ANY, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=safari, version=}]
15:57:56.561 INFO - Server started on port 39602
15:57:56.570 INFO - Launching Safari
15:57:56.579 INFO - Waiting for SafariDriver to connect
15:57:58.044 INFO - Connection opened
15:57:58.046 INFO - Driver connected in 1466 ms
15:57:58.071 INFO - Shutting down
15:57:58.071 INFO - Closing connection
15:57:58.072 INFO - Stopping Safari
15:57:58.123 INFO - Stopping server
15:57:58.124 INFO - Stopping server
15:57:58.132 INFO - Shutdown complete
15:57:58.134 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:16:47'
System info: host: 'L502062.local', ip: '10.10.80.7', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.3', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:58)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:202)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:130)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:680)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:571)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:16:47'
System info: host: 'L502062.local', ip: '10.10.80.7', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.3', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:85)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:16:47'
System info: host: 'L502062.local', ip: '10.10.80.7', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.3', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: SafariDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:58)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:51)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor.execute(SafariDriverCommandExecutor.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:578)
    ... 19 more
15:57:58.139 WARN - Exception: com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: Cannot access execution context
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/veeraa/Documents/workspace/med_selenium/lib/ui/safari_test.py", line 30, in <module>
    MyClass().test()
  File "<string>", line 2, in test
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Selenium2Library/keywords/keywordgroup.py", line 15, in _run_on_failure_decorator
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/veeraa/Documents/workspace/med_selenium/lib/ui/safari_test.py", line 26, in test
    self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/safari/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 138, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Selenium2Library/webdrivermonkeypatches.py", line 11, in execute
    result = self._base_execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 195, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 170, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String
Stacktrace:
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert (JsonToBeanConverter.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert (JsonToBeanConverter.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor.execute (SafariDriverCommandExecutor.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute (RemoteWebDriver.java:578)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession (RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init> (RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init> (RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init> (SafariDriver.java:58)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init> (SafariDriver.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:-2)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor (DefaultDriverProvider.java:85)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance (DefaultDriverProvider.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance (DefaultDriverFactory.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call (DefaultSession.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call (DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run (DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:744)
```

**Appreciate if anyone can help me to resolve this issue?**

Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari driver version is not supported with 2.46.  Try downgrading Selenium Version:

```
pip uninstall selenium
pip install -Iv selenium==2.45 or pip install selenium==2.45
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But I had to downgrade the SELENIUM_SERVER_JAR also to version 2.45

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the same issue, but I just posted an answer here that might help: [Unable to run tests on Safari - Do we need dev certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484045/unable-to-run-tests-on-safari-do-we-need-dev-certificate)

Comment: Thanks Andrew Kincaid